# Can nullptr be used as a type?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, nullptr

I was learning about the usage of `enable_if` and I stumbled upon the following code.

```
template <class T,
         typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value,
                                 T>::type* = nullptr>
void do_stuff(T& t) {
  std::cout << "do_stuff integral\n";
    // an implementation for integral types (int, char, unsigned, etc.)
}
```

The thing that bothers me is that in the template parameter, nullptr is used as a default parameter to the `std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type*` which is also a type.

I am not sure how we can assign a literal to the type. Shouldn't it be `nullptr_t` instead?

Comment: What about default arguments? `void foo(int = 0)`? Doesn't it look similar?

Comment: @Fureeish I see. I never thought assigning default 'value' to the template argument was also possible. Thanks

Comment: Since `template`s can contain both types and values, this is very handy :>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This template accept a non-type second parameter, that is a pointer `typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type *` so `nullptr` is used as default value for this pointer. Note that `typename` in this second parameter is used to make compiler figure out that `::type` as a type, it is not a beginning of usual type template parameter like `typename T`

Answer (score 1):

`nullptr` is not a type, it's a value (of type `nullptr_t`, which can be converted to any pointer type IIRC). Otherwise, any standard usage of `nullptr` like:

```
int* a = nullptr;
```

would not work.

This is an unnamed default template parameter used to allow SFINAE in a template declaration instead of using the return type. It's basically like:

```
template<int=0>
void foo();
```

With the SFINAE trick/`enable_if`.